# Is Three20 allowed?

Tags: iphone, three20

Ive heard news that Apple is turning down Apps that use the three20 framework.My project uses it extensively.Does this mean im running into trouble.

Comment: "Apple is turning down Apps that use the three20 framework." [citation needed]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is old old news.  There was a private API call in Three20 over 1 year ago and it was promptly removed.  When doing your google searches for anything tech-related, I would only show results in the past month, maybe the past year if you want to be accurate.

Answer (score 1):

From the information I was able to gather, it seems that Three20 apps are allowed by Apple. If you check GitHub history of Three20, you'll also notice that several changes have been made to not use private APIs.

Answer (score 1):

Yes Three20 is allowed for AppStroe. We are using from last 2 years for development.

Answer (score 0):

You can check "Three20 App Store Status" on the website of three20 :

http://www.three20.info

You can see on the first page if the lib is good (or not) for the app store.

"As of Dec 23, 2009 : Three20 App Store status: safe"

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to check for memory leaks by using Instruments Leaks.  Especially if you are using the JSON parsing libraries in Three20.

You can Applescript the Simulator to run automated tests if you wish to test for leaks overnight.

Here is a sample:

```
on run
    main()
end run

on main()
    tell application "System Events"
        set myWindow to get window 1 of application process "iOS Simulator"
        set myField to text field 1 of myWindow
    end tell    
    set iterations to 0
    repeat while true
        activate application "iPhone Simulator"
        set iterations to iterations + 1
        log iterations
        tell application "System Events"
            click myField
            keystroke return
        end tell        
    delay 3 
    end repeat
end main
```